# How many types of MagSafe are there?

Tags: magsafe

Now that MagSafe is dead in favor of USB-C, how many types of MagSafe are there and how do I identify which one matches my computer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203207), there are three generations and four types of MagSafe adapters:

- MagSafe

  - "T" Style (2006)
  - "L" Styles (2008, 2010)
- MagSafe 2 (2012)
- [MagSafe 3](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203207) (2021)

The "T" and "L" style are the original MagSafe (or MagSafe 1, if you will) and are compatible with each other.

[image]

As for identifying the adapter to your specific model, Apple also provides an excellent support document:  [Find the right power adapter and cord for your Mac notebook](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201700)

As for the MagSafe being dead, according to [articles written just today](http://www.iclarified.com/59874/apple-patents-magsafe-to-usbc-adapter) about a patent filed by Apple, they may be bringing it back as an adapter (MagSafe to USB-C)

[image]

[MagSafe 3 is not compatible with the older generations](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/430227/5472) since it’s just USB-C power delivery with custom connection and pin layout.

Comment: Upvoted for giving me hope for the future! Just bought the last of the 2015 MacBooks in March because I didn't want to say goodbye to MagSafe, among other things.

Comment: There it is @miken32 !

Comment: @tama I had to replace my MBP in 2020 