# Converter between MagSafe 1/2 and MagSafe 3

Tags: magsafe, macos

Will there be a converter available for connecting one of the old MagSafe or MagSafe 2 power adaptor to the new MagSafe 3 port which is present in the newly released MacBook Pros? I haven't been able to find any yet.

Apple did release such a connector for converting between MagSafe and MagSafe 2:

> MagSafe to MagSafe 2 Converter
> https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD504LL/A/magsafe-to-magsafe-2-converter

Answer (score 16):

- [MagSafe 3 is USB-C power delivery with a pin layout change](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203207) and it is not compatible with older computers or adapters.
- MagSafe 1/2 is a totally different voltage and power signaling specification.

Anything is possible with inverters and power handling, but the size and cost of it would be high. I doubt we will see anything but “snake oil” in this space, but I could always be wrong.

Most of this Wikipedia article covers the older technical details which could lead people to expect a simple adapter like was possible between 1 and 2 but the change for 3 is a substantial one and not a “compatible” one.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MagSafe

Comment: This answer would be even better if you included a link to https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/316401 which explains why these could not ever be compatible in a reasonable manner

Comment: Interesting and thanks @ReinstateMonica3167040 I hadn’t seen that and will need to absorb it before I can edit. Feel free to make an edit if you know what to say

Answer (score 7):

The Apple [MagSafe support document](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203207) mentions the MagSafe to MagSafe 2 converter:

> If your Mac uses MagSafe 2, you can charge your Mac with a MagSafe 2 power adapter or a MagSafe power adapter connected with the MagSafe to MagSafe 2 converter.

But goes on to say that the earlier versions **"aren't compatible"** with MagSafe 3.

> MagSafe 2 and MagSafe power adapters aren't compatible with MagSafe 3.

So it seems very unlikely Apple will be releasing a MagSafe 2-to-3 converter.

Comment: Very useful, thanks. A pity as we have a house full of MagSafe 1 adapters with the MagSafe2 converters on them so everyone can charge.

Answer (score 3):

While not 100% related, this YouTube video has interesting take on this, in relation to retrofitting cable to older Mac Thunderbolt Display.

The guy in this video uses some electronic components to convert the power output from the monitor to Thunderbolt 3 / 4 connection at 45W to power his laptop whilst connected to the display.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=38dEhDV6gZY