# MagSafe charger adapter to a new Mac Air USB-C charger

Tags: mac, charger

I just bought a new Mac Air that uses the USB-C charger but I have 3 of the old MagSafe chargers.  Is there any way that I can buy an adapter so as to not have to throw out these chargers?

Answer (score 2):

No, you should reuse / resell / recycle the old adapters elsewhere as these aren’t fit for your current use case.

MagSafe 1 and 2 are low voltage direct current chargers.
[MagSafe 3](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/430226/converter-between-magsafe-1-2-and-magsafe-3) and USB-C power delivery also are low voltage direct current chargers, but also have to meet the standards for cabling and identification the old adapter can not provide.

Comment: Thank you for the info.  I didn't think I'd be possible but you've confirmed it.  Thanks

Comment: My pleasure. Welcome to the site!

Comment: "typhus" is a great typo~

Comment: Auto wrong FTW @DavidSupportsMonica